# Which CMS or blogging engine supports multiple sites?

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, blogs

Dont know if SO is the appropriate place to ask this question, but anyway ...

I have some sites running Wordpress and maintaining/managing them is a pain. Is there any CMS or blogging platform out there that support multiple sites/blogs in one codebase ? I know there are some hacks for Wordpress but they are quite ugly and do not scale (i need 100-1000 blogs supported). WPMU AFAIK run with subdomains only.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to clarify that i need to serve multiple domains from a single codebase.

Wordpress 3 does have this "Network" feature, but support subdomains/subdirectories only. To add multi-domain support you need to install some plugins (domain mapper), and IMO they are all ugly hacks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain you can use WordPress MU in a sub directory versus a sub domain.

[WordPress Hive](http://wp-hive.com/) is an alternative to WordPress MU. I'd imagine you're going to have to do some more research and reading before you make a decision.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress 3 - scheduled for release this month - combines the code bases of Wordpress and Wordpress MU and supports mutliple sites, multiple domains, etc., out of the box: [Version 3.0 Project Schedule «  WordPress Development Updates](http://wpdevel.wordpress.com/version-3-0-project-schedule/)

Comment: Wordpress 3 only support multiple *subdomains*, not domains.

Answer (score 0):

WPMU will support multiple sites, but it's a bit tricky to implement on some hosts.  WP 3.0 will roll in WPMU's multi-site features sometime very soon.

In the meantime, I use [a WordPress plug-in called Hive](http://wp-hive.com/) to manage multiple installations.  I have some sites set up as subdomains pointing to the same WordPress installation and some sites that are completely separate domains pointing to the same thing.  It's a great way to use one WordPress codebase to manage multiple sites (one set of plug-in upgrades, on set of themes, etc).